# adding images to app bundle permanently

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am adding some images that I need to use in my app in Supporting Files folder(Xcode 4.3). But when I transfer that code to some other machine(like to my supervisor) those images are not available as in I have only their names displayed in red color in that list.
How can I add them permanently?

Comment: "Transfer that code"?  Did you copy the whole project?

Comment: ya I am copying whole project and it builds fine on the other machine, its just that images are somehow lost.

Comment: If they are lost then it shouldn't build just fine.  You should get an error.  Did you create references to things on your machine instead of copying everything locally?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I just wanted to convey that rest of the project is working fine on second machine. Actually the errors that I get are regarding "Image not found" only.

Comment: 'transfer that code' - I'm choosing to believe that he means 'gave access to the source control we are using' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the add files windows, and after you select the images, make sure that distination check box is selected, this check box indicate whether you want to copy the selected items into distention group folder, or just you want a reference to these items

so select the check box, and this will copy the items to application bundle permanently

Comment: Oh, yes. I guess I was missing that earlier. Thanks a lot. I think it will work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The red simply means that XCode can't find the images.

Just because a file appears in a group in Xcode doesn't mean that it's in the same folder as other files in the group :(

I would suspect that you've added images to the group that are somewhere else on your machine. You've then given your boss a copy of your app's folder but that folder doesn't contain those images!

You can see where the files are located in the right hand side inspector when you click on them in XCode.

Comment: Ya they are in a different folder on my system. But I thought since I did "Add existing Files to..", it would have created a copy of them in my project. So, where do I need to copy the original folder now?

Comment: There's a tickbox on the 'add existing file` popup dialog that you can choose to copy them into your folder or not. You could try removing them (references only!) and re-adding them with the checkbox ticked this time. Or you could move them into the folder you want and add them that way.

Comment: Silly me!!..never noticed that. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Put/Copy your images inside xcode's project folder (/Users/SomeUser/mySuperProject/) and then add the images to your project (Supporting Files Group or another group).After that u can use this project anywhere.

Comment: This is true, but you can copy items into the application bundle by selecting the destination check box in the add new files window